# How to push object properties and values into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, object-properties

I have an input field in HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="id-name">
```

I'm generating a random value here:

```
function rand(length, current) {
    current = current || '';
    return length ? rand(--length, "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz".charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 60)) + current) : current;
}
```

and I've defined an empty array:

```
var sample = sample || [];
```

After calling the rand() function, I'm trying to push the randomly generated value into the array, along with two other object properties and values:

```
(function() {
    $("#id-name").val(rand(5));
    var value = $("#id-name").val();
    sample.push({acct:"sample-code", labels:"sample label", trackingcode: value});
})();
```

I can't get the push method to insert the data into the 'sample' array. I've already tried referencing [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097366/pushing-a-multiple-attributed-item-to-an-array-javascript), but wasn't able to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I don't think it's pushing correctly because when I run:

```
alert(sample);
```

all I get is [object Object]

[Here's a jsFiddle link to test things out.](http://jsfiddle.net/miketang/xdrhm/)

Comment: What makes you think it's not working?

Comment: You're probably running your code before the DOM is ready, so the `id-name` element doesn't exist yet. Or you're doing something asynchronous. Not enough info in the question, but your `.push()` code is correct.

Comment: works for me -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nA8B4/) (PS: jsFiddle waits for DOM ready) ?

Comment: Edited above to give more context. adeneo, I checked console and all I got was [object Object]. Is that functioning as expected in jsFiddle?

Comment: Don't alert, use console.log and you'll see the real thing.

Comment: The fiddle you provided looks just fine to me. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/67589325/Screenshots/1364942261.png

Comment: @adeneo Yeah, you have the default `window`'s `load` wrapper set in the top left of the fiddle.

Comment: `[object Object]` is exactly what you should be getting, as alerts only outputs strings, not objects, you'll need to use the console for that, as noted by @bfavaretto above.

Comment: You guys were right - thanks everyone for the quick feedback! I wasn't aware that alert only outputs strings. Still learning basic things like this everyday :)